# How to check whether username and password have been saved in keychain

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keychain

i have saved my username and password in keychain but how can i come to know my username and password is stored in keychain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SFHFKeychainUtils to save and retrieve strings saved in the Keychian...
You can find more in this mine answer: [what is the best way for saving username and High Score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448525/what-is-the-best-way-for-saving-username-and-high-score/5448815#5448815)