# How to remember the username and password?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am working on an iPhone/iOS app. It have a login page with two text fields "username" & "Password" 3rd option is "Remember me" Now i want to save username & password when "remember me" is checked. Please tell me how can I save password & username. Plz give me an easiest way.

Comment: Store the username & password in [Keychain Services Tasks for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752468/how-to-get-the-nsuserdefault-value-in-other-viewcontrollers

Comment: You can use keychain to store sensitive data... I've posted some other answers about this topic and you can find an answer reading them, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448525/what-is-the-best-way-for-saving-username-and-high-score/5448815#5448815) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309110/error-saving-in-the-keychain-with-iphone-sdk/5625186#5625186).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972092/ios-how-to-store-username-password-within-an-app Take a look here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume username and password are text fields.

```
NSUserDefaults *pref=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[pref setObject:username.text forKey:@"username"];
[pref setObject:password.text forKey:@"password"];
```

When you want to access the saved values do:-

```
NSString *username,*password;
NSUserDefaults *prefs= [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
username=[prefs objectForKey:@"username"];
password=[prefs objectForKey:@"password"];
```

Comment: Don't use the user defaults system for passwords.