# Keychain doesn't get data

Tags: ios, keychain

I use the common Keychain-wrapper from here:
[iOS: How to store username/password within an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972092/ios-how-to-store-username-password-wihtin-an-app)

Here is my Set-Code:

```
    KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Animex" accessGroup:nil];
[keychain setObject:username forKey:@"Username"];
[keychain setObject:password forKey:@"Password"];

[keychain release];
```

Here is my Get-Code:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *password = [prefs stringForKey:@"Password"];

if ([password length] != 0)
{
    return password;
}
else
{
    return nil;
}
```

I only get NIL back, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are storing the values using `KeychainItemWrapper` then trying to retrieve them using `NSUserDefaults`. Those are 2 completely different backing stores so you need to use `KeychainItemWrapper` to retrieve your values. Also you should use `kSecValueData` and `kSecAttrAccount`.

The article you linked to actually has the answer in there.

```
//Set
KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Animex" accessGroup:nil];
[keychain setObject:username forKey:kSecAttrAccount];
[keychain setObject:password forKey:kSecValueData];

[keychain release];
```

```
//Retrieve
KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Animex" accessGroup:nil];
NSString *password = [keychainItem objectForKey:kSecValueData];

if ([password length] != 0)
{
    return password;
}
else
{
    return nil;
}
[keychain release];
```

Comment: Hi Joe, does it matter if I store the password for key `kSecValueData`? I've seen many examples online where users are storing usernames/passwords the other way around to how you have done. Is there an incorrect way?

Comment: @Sooper I posted them backwards in the first example, I apologize for that.