# asihttprequest auto login after the first time

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, authentication, asihttprequest

I am using asihttprequest library to make asynchronous requests to the php web services. For login i am using php login web service. My problem is that the user has to login everytime the app is launched. Is there any way to check if the user was logged in before, if so then he should be auto login the next time. We can use a switch for "Keep me logged in" purpose(switch on for "Keep me logged in" and switch off for "login required for the next time").

I think that the default has to be that the user should not have to sign in when using the app... after the first time. Maybe when they sign in the first time we note that the default has them logged in unless they check a box or a switch that they want to log in each time they use?  They user should have a location where they can change their preference should they choose that option and decide to change it later to stay open.

I am using this code for login:

```
-(void)callWebService
{

     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"My_Url"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request=[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setPostValue:emailField.text forKey:@"email"];
    [request setPostValue:pwdField.text forKey:@"pass"];


    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setTimeOutSeconds:100];
    [request setUseSessionPersistence:NO];
    [request setUseCookiePersistence:NO];
    [request startAsynchronous];


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should see this post

[iOS: How to store username/password within an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972092/ios-how-to-store-username-password-within-an-app)

and then before you make the call to your server , check if the values exists in the Keychain.