# What's the best way to keep ios app signed in?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, security, authentication

I'm working on a ios app need to communicate with server. When user first time launch the app, he's prompted to input his username and password. Once he's authenticated, i want to keep him signed in until he signed out explicitly.

after digging in Apple documents for several hours, I can point out two methods to implement the idea:
<1> use http basic/digest authentication. 
Once user is authenticated, i save username and password in keychain. Whenever the server requires authentication, by implementing **connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:** function, app can load username and password, and construct legal **[NSURLCredential](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/AuthenticationChallenges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009507-SW1)**. Certainly it will work, but every request must authenticate one time and transfer user secret frequently.

<2> use http cookie
Once user is authenticated, the server response with a unique token in cookie. Depend on the feature **[The URL loading system automatically sends any stored cookies appropriate for an NSURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/URLOverview.html)**. I'm not sure whether the cookie will be lost when user kill the app.

Do you think the two methods is ok? which one is better? Is there any other methods to do the same thing?

I notice many clients(twitter/facebook/...) keep user signed in, what method they use?
Thanks;

BTW, I have saved username and password in keychain, but to keep signed in, I think there is more work to do.

Comment: Save your user name and password in device keychain. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972092/ios-how-to-store-username-password-within-an-app

Comment: I have saved username and password in keychain, but to keep signed in, there is more work to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't about cookie storage. But when you add user name and password to `keychain`, You have to `clean up` keychain when app get `uninstalled`. Otherwise it may keep in `keychain`, evenafter your app get uninstalled. Because `keychain` have key pair storage, but not app based storage. You can use `NSUserDefault` to store login details. I think it's a better way to do this..

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for keychain :

[KeyChain sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007797)

you can also use NSUserDefault

Comment: nope nsuserdefaults is not a secure way ,keychain is for it .Use keychain

Answer (score 0):

try this one and save your authentication username password in NSUserDefaults. It's provide globally in application.

For Save your data try this

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:isValid forKey:@"Username"];
[defaults setObject:accessLevel forKey:@"Password"];
```

And for get data try this one

```
NSUserDefaults *defaultsCheck = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString  * userIDCheck = [defaultsCheck objectForKey:@"Username"];
NSString *accessLevelCheck = [defaultsCheck objectForKey:@"Password"];
```

Comment: Not a good idea to use NSUserDefaults for Username/Passwords. Instead you should use Keychain that it is secure and will remain for your app even if you remove your app and install it again. Take a look at documentation for the use of keychain.