# SSKeyChain: how to lock this keychain?

Tags: objective-c, password-protection, keychain, sskeychain

My cocoa app will have the following features:
1. password protected login. User will have to enter the password in order to use the app
2. once logged in, user can create some personal profile, which profile can store some secure info like password.

After some research, I was told that I should use the KeyChain in order to save the secure info (so in my case, the login password and the secure info within each personal profile).

Seems like there is a good KeyChain wrapper, SSKeyChain, can be used to achieve my goal (as I'm not too familiar with c lang so using the apple's keychain will be hard for me) and I have also found some samples of using SSKeyChain [iOS: How to store username/password within an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972092/ios-how-to-store-username-password-within-an-app/13641196#13641196):

```
To save a password:

[SSKeychain setPassword:@"AnyPassword" forService:@"AnyService" account:@"AnyUser"]
To retrieve a password:

NSString *password = [SSKeychain passwordForService:@"AnyService" account:@"AnyUser"];
```

However I'm not sure if I need to "protect" my keychain:
1. when calling setPassword:forService:account: should I include a plaintext password? or do I need to encrypt my password first? also when setting the service name, should I just simply include my app name
2. if password can be retrieved by using passwordForService: easily then it seems like it's not safe? as other app can also call the same method to retrieve the keychain? (provided that they know the service name and account)

I have read the apple documentaion: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH204-TP9

and seems like you have to "lock" and "unlock" this keychain. I have checked the SSKeyChain doc http://docs.samsoff.es/SSKeychain/Classes/SSKeychain.html but couldn't find any method to "lock" and "unlock" such keychain. So how am I going to protect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Keychain Services from the system limits each application to only have access to it's own keychain items by default. The locking and unlocking are all handled behind the scenes of Keychain Services.

> When you use Xcode to create an application, Xcode adds an application-identifier entitlement to the application bundle. Keychain Services uses this entitlement to grant the application access to its own keychain items.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html

Comment: thanks, I have added SSKeyChain to my project and works fine. However here comes my question. Using KeyChain or SSKeyChain doesn't seem a good way of protecting the app, as keychain can be easily deleted from the keychain access. If it's deleted, then password will be gone app becomes unprotected.

Comment: @Josh what do you mean by 'protecting the app'? keychain is a secure place for you to store data needed by your app.

Comment: Hi, as I said my app will implement the password protected feature, which means user will first have to enter the password in order to use the app (the idea is very similar to the passcode of your iphone, if you don't enter the right code/password, you won't be able to use the app). So as I said it's not a good idea to use keychain just for this purpose.

Comment: Keychain is as good a place as any to store the password but you could store it in your app directory as well. You could store an encrypted version of the password as well. Have a look at http://www.raywenderlich.com/6603/basic-security-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2

Comment: I maybe wrong (which is very likely :) ) but I have raised a question in raywenderlich.com's forum:http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=1977&start=20 as I'm not sure if the app is secured enough or not.