# Saving data in app and loading in iOS programming?

Tags: ios, save, uitextfield

I have three text fields in one view controller and I want to save save each input the user puts.
I have no idea on how to save data so I need help. It is three pieces of information that makes the user create an account.  The user will use it to log into his account.  Do I need to make an array of text fields? If so, how?

Comment: Use `NSUserDefaults` for non-secure information, and use the keychain for secure information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS: How to store username/password within an app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972092/ios-how-to-store-username-password-within-an-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `KeychainItemWrapper` class for storing secure data.
First download the **.h** and **.m** files at this [github link](https://gist.github.com/dhoerl/1170641).
Now add them to your project by drag and drop. Don't forget to do this:

[image]

In your app, navigate to

`Build phases -> Link Libraries` and add **`Security.framework`**.
Now in your `viewController`'s **implementation file**, import the class you have just added.

```
#import "KeychainItemWrapper.h"
```

Suppose you have three `textField`s for entering *username* *email* and *password*, you create outlets for them as:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *userNameTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *emailTextField;
```

Now, in you `signUpButtonClick` method you can store these fields using the following code:

```
- (IBAction)signUpButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    [keychainItem setObject:self.emailTextField.text forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrService];
    [keychainItem setObject:self.passwordTextField.text forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
    [keychainItem setObject:self.userNameTextField.text forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
}
```

Later, if you want to retrieve these fields, you can simply get them using the following code:

```
NSString *email = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrService];
NSString *password =
[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *username = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
```

**Note:**

1. The password field is stored as data as we use the key kSecValueData. So it should be converted to string for viewing purposes. This is what I have done above.
2. (__bridge id) should be used only in ARC projects.

Hope this helps! :)