# How to keep user logged in after quitting an app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking

How do I keep my user still logged in after they have quit the app or restart their phone (I used Facebbok account by the way)? I know this might have been answered before but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: do you wants user to keep login for facebook or for your app?

Comment: You can maybe store the authenticaiton credential in NSUserDefaults or if you're using OAuthentication, there's an AFNetworking [AFOAuthenticationCredential storeCredential: withIdentifier:]; method that stores it for you. On app relaunch, perhaps you could check for the credential in the NSUserDefaults or using [AFOAuthenticationCredential retrieveCredentialWithIdentifier:]; method if you're using OAuth with Facebook.

Comment: I want to keep the user logged-in in my app

Comment: Then use NSUserDefaults. it would be best option

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972092/ios-how-to-store-username-password-within-an-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the user credentials securely by using the iOS Keychain https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW3