# iOS - How to save password permanently?

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5

I have the following code:

```
NSData *secret = [pssword dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    query =@{
             (__bridge id)kSecClass:(__bridge id) kSecClassGenericPassword,
             (__bridge id)kSecAttrService:@"My App",
             (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount:usrid,
             (__bridge id)kSecValueData:secret
             };

    OSStatus status = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) query, NULL);

    if(status != errSecSuccess)
    {
         NSLog(@"Unable add item with key =%@ error:%ld",secret,status);
    }
```

It seem that the password and userid, is only saved for the session. Every time I refresh the simulator or re-launch the application the password and userid disappear / gone for good.

How do I save them to the keychain DB permanently please?

Thank you

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6972305/2053537

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSUserDefaults to do that simply
To Save data use when you have the password (for example if the password is NSString)

```
     NSString*userIDString=@"myPassordStringXXX";
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:userIDString forKey:@"passwordKey"];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

To retrive the data you can use

```
NSString*passwordString=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"passwordKey"]
```

Comment: @georgeOfTheJungle is it works for you ?
is that what you want ?

Comment: @georgeOfTheJungle Great News :) , glad to hear that