# Storing username & password in iOS 8 -- is an ARC-ified KeychainItemWrapper still necessary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, keychain

Is an ARC-ified KeychainItemWrapper, as described at [iOS: How to store username/password within an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972092/ios-how-to-store-username-password-within-an-app/6972305#6972305), still necessary for storing username & password info in iOS 8?

Most guidance I see in this area comes from 2011-2012. I've heard that there's a better way to store username/password info now, but I haven't been able to find out what that is!

That post also points to the samples repo https://gist.github.com/dhoerl/1170641 as the best place. Is there a more "legit" version of an ARC-ified KeychainItemWrapper?

Comment: Check out [SSKeychain](https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain)