# Is it smart to use UserDefaults to save logged in username in login?

Tags: mysql, swift, authentication

I am currently developing a Swift app with a mySQL backend. The app will consist of a user logging in and getting access to a UITableView.

To implement the login screen. My initial thought is to have the user login and save whatever username was successful as the **UserDefault** value.

Then I can pass that username as the parameter for fetching the UITableView using JSON.

Comment: Use UserDefaults for saving app preferences. Use CoreData for storing logged in user details

Comment: But in a similar sense right, whichever username is last entered in a username TextField that is also correct in the DB is what is going to be stored right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing iOS app's user password and username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35802704/storing-ios-apps-user-password-and-username)